# Parametrized query from .net to Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

this is my table in oracle:

[image]

I'm trying to do this:

```
  selectCmd = "select * from scott.BONUS where ename like '% :f4  %'";
        var par = cmd.CreateParameter();
        par.DbType = DbType.String;
        par.ParameterName = "f4";
        par.Value = "fsd";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(par);

        cmd.CommandText = selectCmd;
        con.Open();
```

my problem is the part after the 'like' .. I've tried many things w/o success.
In some of the tries the reader came back empty while in others an exception has been thrown.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to put the % in the value of the parameter, not in the query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is looking for something containing the literal sequence of characters *space, colon, f, 4*. You mean:

```
like '%' || :f4 || '%'
```

(edited to reflect correction by Stephen ODonnell, comments)

Or easier; just use

```
like :f4
```

And put the `%` in the value:

```
par.Value = "%" + "fsd" + "%";
```

(expanded for convenience, under the assumption that "fsd" needs to be a variable or similar in the real code)

Comment: thanks, I prefer you'r first suggestion but it didn't worked for me. the second did.

Comment: In Oracle the first suggestion should be coded like '%'|| :f4 || '%' - the || is the string concatenate operator, not +

Comment: @StephenODonnell thanks; my lack of Oracle-ness is shining through. Close, though ;p